# PostgreSQL: Is there a way to create multiple tables using a prefix on a function?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to create multiple tables using a function, either having a prefix or a suffix. It's something like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION c_table (number int)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'aaa' || number (some_text varchar);
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'aab' || number (some_text varchar);
end;
$$
```

Is there a way to accomplish that without hard coding each of those tables? Using some dynamic way to create those multiple tables?

I tried to run down the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION c_table (number int)
RETURNS int
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aaa || to_char(number, '0000') (some_text varchar);
END;
```

and was expecting it to create a function to allow me to create multiple tables, each one with a prefix or a suffix (for example: running select c_table(12) would create the table schema.aaa0012)

But when I run it I receive the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"
> LINE 7:  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aaa || to_char(number, '0000') (...
> ^
>
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 111

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this, using EXECUTE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place? I suspect partitioning would be a far better option

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens! It worked well.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.c_table(number integer)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
begin
 execute 'create table if not exists aaa' || trim(to_char(number, '0000')) || '(other_number int)';
 execute 'create table if not exists aab' || trim(to_char(number, '0000')) || '(other_number int)';

end;
$BODY$;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dynamic statements it would be something like this:

```
create or replace function c_table (p_number int)
returns void
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    execute format('create table if not exists %I (id int primary key, data text)', 
   concat('aaa', lpad(p_number::varchar, 4, '0')));--left padding with zeroes until 4 chars
end;
$$
```